# Exec tag in Ant file

Tags: bash, ant

I work with bash script ant Ant. I want to execute bash script  inline build.xml file.
my bash script is here

```
for f in `cat lg-media-file-list`
do
    subdir=`dirname $f`
    mkdir -p ${destination}$subdir
    cp $f ${destination}${subdir}
done
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: Why do you want to execute it as bash script not an ant ask?

Comment: I want to have code one plase .only in build.xml file

Comment: No, you don't. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Ant is a *matrix dependency language* while Shell scripts are procedural languages. The purpose of a *matrix dependency language* is to allow the build description to determine the order of execution. Procedural languages allow you to define an order.

You can embed some scripting into Ant build scripts (usually using JavaScript), but this is mainly to define customized tasks. I've been working with Ant since version 1.5 came out, and I have done this less than a 1/2 dozen times. The last time I defined a filter task to lowercase file names as they were copied over for a WAR. (Don't ask why the files weren't cased correctly in the first place).

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Is this part of a build process? If it is, why not simply use the already defined Ant tasks that can do this? Are you attempting to use Ant as a procedural scripting tool? If so, you're asking for a whole lot of hurt. Ant isn't made for that.

Please give us a bit more information about your situation. What exactly do you want to accomplish? You mentioned *I want to have code one place.*. Do you know about functions? You can define functions in BASH and via your `.bashrc` file, have access to them as if they are shell scripts. Your code will be in *one place* that way.

However, until we know what you want to do, it's difficult to figure out what to advise you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is not supported as an inline script, mainly because it is not implemented in Java. See

- [Script task doco](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html)
- [BSF Bean Scripting Framework](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bsf.html)

I have recoded your example as [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task):

```
new File("lg-media-file-list").eachLine {
    def srcFile = new File(it)
    def destDir = new File(properties.destination, srcFile.parent)

    ant.copy(file:srcFile, todir:destDir)
}
```

The following example shows how this can be integrated into your build.xml

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── lg-media-file-list
├── lib
│   └── groovy-all-2.1.6.jar
├── src
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   ├── file4.txt
│   └── file5.txt
└── target
    └── src
        ├── file1.txt
        ├── file2.txt
        ├── file3.txt
        ├── file4.txt
        └── file5.txt
```

The groovy jar can be downloaded from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22groovy-all%22%20AND%20v%3a%222.1.6%22)

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="copy-files">

   <property name="destination" location="target"/>

   <path id="build.path">
      <pathelement location="lib/groovy-all-2.1.6.jar"/>
   </path>

   <target name="copy-files">
      <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

      <groovy>
         new File("lg-media-file-list").eachLine {
            def srcFile = new File(it)
            def destDir = new File(properties.destination, srcFile.parent)

            ant.copy(file:srcFile, todir:destDir)
         }
      </groovy>
   </target>

   <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="${destination}"/>
   </target>

</project>
```

### lg-media-file-list

```
src/file1.txt
src/file2.txt
src/file3.txt
src/file4.txt
src/file5.txt
```